# How to parseInt a string with leading 0

Tags: javascript, string, parseint

How to parseInt "09" into 9 ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

include the radix:

```
parseInt("09", 10);
```

Answer (score 12):

This has been driving me nuts -`parseInt("02")` works but not `parseInt("09")`.

As others have said, the solution is to specify base 10:

```
parseInt("09", 10);
```

There's a good explanation for this behaviour [here](http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/articles/issues-parseint-javascript)

> ... In Javascript numbers starting
>   with zero are considered octal and
>   there's no 08 or 09 in octal, hence
>   the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do:

`Number('09') => 9`

This returns the integer 9 on IE7, IE8, FF3, FF4, and Chrome 10.

Answer (score 5):

Re-implement the existing parseInt so that if it is called with one argument then "10" is automatically included as the second argument.

```
(function(){
  var oldParseInt = parseInt;
  parseInt = function(){
    if(arguments.length == 1)
    {
      return oldParseInt(arguments[0], 10);    
    }
    else
    {
      return oldParseInt.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
parseInt("09", 10);
```

or

```
parseInt(parseFloat("09"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
parseInt("09",10);
```

returns 9 here.

It is odd.

```
alert(parseInt("09")); // shows 9. (tested with Opera 10)
```

Comment: @JonH: Right. Thanks for warning. Since he wrote string instead of String I was mistaken.

Comment: Depending on the browser and version parseInt("09") can return 0.
It is a bug.

Comment: @JonH: can you please check this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp   document.write(parseInt("010") also displays 10 here.

Comment: @JonH: It's not actually a bug. ECMAScript allows implementations to treat numbers with leading zeros as octal. Some implementations do, and some don't.

Comment: @MatthewCrumley—an old comment but what the heck - [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) removes that behaviour, so compliant browsers *should* treat `parseInt('08')` as base 10.