# How do I parse the following string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to parseInt a string with leading 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545164/how-to-parseint-a-string-with-leading-0)
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

How can I parse the "09" into number?

alert(parseInt("09"));

This returns me 0 ..Why is that and how do I fix this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug (basic gist, give a base to the parseInt function because parsing a string with a leading 0 tells parseInt to treat the number as octal, but 9 (and 8) are invalid octal digits) the linked question also provides at least one additional solution as well as lots of groovy info. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the ***base*** as well:

```
alert(parseInt("09", 10));  // outputs 9
```

Comment: This is because if a string contains a leading 0, it will be parsed as octal by default.