# Problems with javascript "parseInt()"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)
>   [How to parseInt a string with leading 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545164/how-to-parseint-a-string-with-leading-0)

```
document.write(parseInt("07"));
```

Produces "7"

```
document.write(parseInt("08"));
```

Produces "0"

This is producing problems for me (sorry for this babble, I have to or I can't submit the question).  Anyone know why it's being stupid or if there is a better function?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you argument begins with 0, it will be parsed as octal, and 08 is not a valid octal number.   Provide a second argument `10` which specifies the radix - a base 10 number.

```
document.write(parseInt("08", 10));
```

Answer (score 7):

use this modification

```
parseInt("08",10);
```

rules for `parseInt(string, radix)`

If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:

- If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
- If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
- If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)

Answer (score 2):

You want `parseInt('08', 10)` to tell it to parse as a decimal.

Answer (score 2):

You just using input parameters of that function in a bit wrong way. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) for more info. Basically :

> The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.
>
> The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be
> used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the
> number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a
> decimal number.
>
> If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
> - If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is
>   deprecated
> - If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10
>   (decimal)

So 07 and 08 is parsed into octal . That's why 07 is 7 and 08 is 0 (it is rounded to closest)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
parseInt('08', 10)
```

it will produce 8