# Weird javascript output

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workarounds for JavaScript parseInt octal bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug)

I was learning the parseInt() function of javascript and was just trying out, and out of nowhere

```
parseInt('08')  returns 0
```

moreover,

```
parseInt('07')  returns 7 //which is correct
```

but again

```
parseInt('09')   returns 0 // really, are you kidding me.?
```

Either I am crazy or I am missing something?

Comment: You last example (with '9') is a typo - you get the surprising result from '09', not '9'.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545164/how-to-parseint-a-string-with-leading-0

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318385/problems-with-javascript-parseint

Comment: parseInt('9') returns 9 for me. But '08' returns 0 as you said. Totally weird. Never seen this before. FF latest.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+parseint

Comment: @techfoobar - see the related posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the [radix](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp):

```
parseInt('08', 10);  // base 10 radix
```

Running your javascript thru [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) will call this out as well.

From the documentation, parseInt parses the string as octal when the string starts with a 0, if no radix is specified.

Answer (score 3):

Its because its doing octal when the string starts with `0`.

You should pass the radix of 10 as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're. Only `parseInt` obeys rules for octal numbers and applies them when the string begins with 0.