# how do I add these strings and not concatenate them

Tags: javascript

My code just purely concatnates them and I want it to add them instead.

```
 <FORM NAME="Calc">
<TR>
<TD>
Number 1 <INPUT TYPE="text"   NAME="n1" Size="16">
Number 2 <INPUT TYPE="text"   NAME="n2" Size="16">
Answer<INPUT TYPE="text"   NAME="ans" Size="16">

<br>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="one"   VALUE="  +  " OnClick="Calc.ans.value = eval(Calc.n1.value + Calc.n2.value)">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
Calc.ans.value = (+Calc.n1.value) + (+Calc.n2.value);
```

You don't need to use `eval()` here. In fact, you should (almost) never use `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Calc.ans.value = parseInt(Calc.n1.value) + parseInt(Calc.n2.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more safe (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318385/problems-with-javascript-parseint)):

```
Calc.ans.value = parseInt(Calc.n1.value, 10) + parseInt(Calc.n2.value, 10)
```

Comment: It's safer than using `parseInt()` without a radix, but the `+` operator doesn't have the issue mentioned in the page you linked to. Plus, are you sure that the numbers OP wants to use are limited to integers?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you! ;)