# convert string to number node.js

Tags: node.js, string, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert req.params to Number because that is what I defined in my schema for year param.

I have tried

```
req.params.year = parseInt( req.params.year, 10 );
```

and

```
Number( req.params.year);
```

and

```
1*req.params.year;
```

but non of them works. 
Do I need to install something?

Comment: Im sorry i didnt see the rest of the code you posted. Then try parseInt(req.params.year.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''),10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with javascript "parseInt()"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318385/problems-with-javascript-parseint)

Comment: can you console req.params.year and let me know what you get.

Comment: req. **prams** .year or req. **params** .year?

Comment: yep that was a typing mistake

Comment: When I do console.log(req.params.year) I get 2016...
When I do console.log(typeof req.params.year) I get a string that is why I'm trying to convert it to Number

Comment: Can you show a complete example with server code and curl or browser call?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You do not have to install something.

```
parseInt(req.params.year, 10);
```

should work properly.

```
console.log(typeof parseInt(req.params.year)); // returns 'number'
```

What is your output, if you use parseInt? is it still a string?

Comment: I think you are using express right? i never used this package, but could it be, the params are just read-only? what, if you create a own variable? `var p = parseInt(req.params.year);`

Comment: What is the different? Why does it work in this way? Sorry I'm learning nodejs so I'm curious.

Comment: @Sang Đặng There is not difference. The variable req.params is created by the express-package and it is set read-only. So you have to declare an own read-write variable.

Comment: Ah, that's why he can't put it back in the first try (in his question above.) Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: parseint is not defined` with `  const { a } = req.body;
  console.log(parseint(a))` in `app.post`. parseInt is written like this, my fault.

Answer (score 15):

Using parseInt() is a bad idea mainly because it never fails. Also because some results can be unexpected, like in the case of INFINITY.
Below is the function for handling unexpected behaviour.

```
function cleanInt(x) {
    x = Number(x);
    return x >= 0 ? Math.floor(x) : Math.ceil(x);
}
```

See results of below test cases.

```
console.log("CleanInt: ", cleanInt('xyz'), " ParseInt: ", parseInt('xyz'));
console.log("CleanInt: ", cleanInt('123abc'), " ParseInt: ", parseInt('123abc'));
console.log("CleanInt: ", cleanInt('234'), " ParseInt: ", parseInt('234'));
console.log("CleanInt: ", cleanInt('-679'), " ParseInt: ", parseInt('-679'));
console.log("CleanInt: ", cleanInt('897.0998'), " ParseInt: ", parseInt('897.0998'));
console.log("CleanInt: ", cleanInt('Infinity'), " ParseInt: ", parseInt('Infinity'));
```

result:

```
CleanInt:  NaN  ParseInt:  NaN
CleanInt:  NaN  ParseInt:  123
CleanInt:  234  ParseInt:  234
CleanInt:  -679  ParseInt:  -679
CleanInt:  897  ParseInt:  897
CleanInt:  Infinity  ParseInt:  NaN
```

Comment: this is not quite correct. parseInt('123abc')) throws an error, it doesn't validate as number 123

Comment: I am not sure about your envoroment. I have given output based on node version v10.2.1.

Comment: On node 13.8 parseInt('123abc') -> 123

Answer (score 4):

You can parse string to number in several ways.

-`Number()`

-`parseInt()`

-`parseFloat()`

Example:

`Number("256.123") //returns 256.123`

`Number("252px") //returns NaN`

`parseInt("256.123") //returns 256`

`parseInt("256px") //returns 256`

`parseFloat("256") //returns 256`

`parseFloat("256.123") //returns 256.123`

`parseFloat("256.23px") //returns 256.23`

Answer (score 3):

*Not a full answer*
 Ok so this is just to supplement the information about parseInt, which is still very valid. Express doesn't allow the req or res objects to be modified at all (immutable). So if you want to modify/use this data effectively, you must copy it to another variable (var year = req.params.year).