# javascript parseInt error conversion

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, substring, parseint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parseInt a string with leading 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545164/how-to-parseint-a-string-with-leading-0)

I'm using Google Chrome ver. 21.0.1180.89

I execute:

```
var a="07:30";
console.log(a.substring(0,2)+" --> "+parseInt(a.substring(0,2)));
```

the output is right: "07 --> 7" **OK**

I execute:

```
var a="08:30";
console.log(a.substring(0,2)+" --> "+parseInt(a.substring(0,2)));
```

the output is right: "08 --> 0" **WRONG**

why?

Comment: the leading 0 denotes OCTAL: 00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,10 so 08 and 09 are invalid. Add a radix as mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String begins with "0" taken as octal. You have to set radix 10 in `parseInt()`

Try this,

```
var a="08:30";
console.log(a.substring(0,2)+" --> "+parseInt(a.substring(0,2), 10));​
```

Answer (score 0):

add a radix(base): `parseInt(a.substring(0,2), 10)`. What's happening is your js engine is trying to guess what base the string is, and it's guessing wrongly, so you need to tell the engine what base to use (`2` for binary, `8` for octal`10` for decimal, `16` for hex, etc)

Comment: In [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) that behaviour is removed, but it persists in browsers, perhaps for backwards compatibility. I wonder how much code actually depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parseInt(a.substring(0,2),10);

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` take 2 parameters, the `string` to parse and the `radix` which is optionnal (but required with JSHint/JSLint).
If you don't pass the {radix{ parameter, `parseInt` will "choose" the best for the string you passed, so for the `08` string, it will take the octal radix and not the decimal one (the one you want).

**TL;DR** Always set the radix when using `parseInt`.

source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with time just to offer a different solution you could try doing it like this:

```
var clock = '07:30';
var time = {
  hours: +clock.split(':')[0],
  minutes: +clock.split(':')[1]
}
```