# parseInt() functionis not working

Tags: javascript

I have a input element to accept number type. I know javascript takes input as a string. so I am using `parseInt()` to convert into `integer`. but it is not working.

My code is:

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="6"><br><br><br><br><br>B1<br> Salary/Pension:</td>
    <td>(1) Salary (excluding all allowances, perquisites and profit in lieu of salary</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="sal" value="0" name="sal" placeholder="" class="form-control "></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>(2) Allowances not exempt</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="allowance" value="0" name="allowance" placeholder="" class="form-control "></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>(3)Value of perquisites</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="perquisites" value="0" name="perquisites" placeholder="" class="form-control "></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>(4) Profits in lieu of salary</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="profit" name="profit" value="0" placeholder="" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>(5)Deduction u/s 16</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="ded16" name="ded16" value="0" placeholder="" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>(6)Income chargable under the head 'Salaries':</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="inchargesal" value="0" name="inchargesal" placeholder="" class="form-control" readonly></td>
</tr>
```

//js part is:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function change() {
        f = a + b + c + d - e;
        alert(f);
        $('#inchargesal').removeAttr('readonly').val(f);
    }
    $('#sal').on('change', function() {

        var a = parseInt(document.getElementsById("sal").value);
        alert("hi");
        change();
    });
    $('#allowance').on('change', function() {
        b = parseInt(document.getElementById("allowance").value)

        change();
    });
    $('#perquisites').on('change', function() {
        c = parseInt(document.getElementsById("perquisites").value);
        change();
    });
    $('#profit').on('change', function() {
        d = parseInt(document.getElementsById("profit").value);
        change();
    });
    $('#ded16').on('change', function() {
        e = parseInt(document.getElementsById("ded16").value);
        change();
    });
});
```

here to notice is, when I use alert("hi") above the `parseInt` statement then alert works fine, however when I use it after that, alert("hi") doesn't work.

what's going wrong? please help.

Comment: You misspelled `getElementsById`, should be no `s` in there

Comment: Open your browser console and check for errors. Your code uses `getElementsById()` but the method is actually `getElementById()`.

Comment: Also it's confusing to mix jQuery and browser DOM APIs like that.

Comment: thank you all , it is working now.

Comment: yes @ibrahimmahrir , I've corrected the code now. thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parseInt a string with leading 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545164/how-to-parseint-a-string-with-leading-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect method of document. There is no such method saying `getElementsById()`. In HTML DOM the `id` field is unique so it can never be `getElements` but `getElement`. Use `getElementById('id')` to make it work.

Also its always better to check `console` first where most of your problems can be resolved on your own. 
Console - 
[image]

Comment: i am using dreamweaver, how to check console there?

Comment: added a screenshot of what I am referring to.